# php/mysql: get data from one table, convert and insert in another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, ldap

Ok I will try to explain, (I am Portuguese lol).

I have a Database where I have the fallowing MySQL:

Database: ad
Table: notebooks
Fields: ID, tag, so, lastlogon, lastlogh

My ldap query gets data from ldap server (active directory) and stores it in my MySQL database (ad/notebooks).
I get tag which is tag number is unique.
I get so which is the OS installed in the notebook.
I get lastlogh which is the last logon time stamp, and it is unique too.
ID field is auto increment and key but I can set the tag filed to be key.

I have a config_notebooks.php where I set all the variables to connect to ldap and MySQL servers.

```
<?php
/*------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
//setting your variables
/*------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
//ldap host
$host = "ldap://HEICPT1VIA01.HEIWAY.NET";
//ldap user
$user = "domain\user";
//ldap password
$pswd = "pssw";
//ldap base structure
$dn = "OU=NotebookM2,OU=WorkstationsM2,OU=PT1,DC=heiway,DC=net";;
//attributs to search and get
$attrs = array("cn","operatingsystem","lastlogon");
//sql host
$sqlhost="localhost"; 
//sql user
$sqluser="root";
//sql password
$sqlpswd="";
//sql database
$database="ad";
//sql table
$table="notebooks";
?>
```

Now the query script

```
<?php
/*------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
//Query script
/*------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
include 'config_notebooks.php';
$filter = $_POST['filter']."=".$_POST['keyword']."*";
//connect to db
$con = mysql_connect("$sqlhost","$sqluser",""); 
if (!$con) 
{ 
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
} 

//connect to active directory
$ad = ldap_connect($host)
  or die( "Could not connect!" );
  
  // Set version number
ldap_set_option($ad, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3)
 or die ("Could not set ldap protocol");
  
  // Binding to ldap server
$bd = ldap_bind($ad, $user, $pswd)
  or die ("Could not bind");

$search = ldap_search($ad, $dn, $filter, $attrs)
      or die ("ldap search failed");

$entries = ldap_get_entries($ad, $search);
$sel = mysql_select_db("ad", $con); 
if (!$sel) 
{ 
die('Could not select DB: ' . mysql_error()); 
} 

for ($i=0; $i<$entries["count"]; $i++) 
{ 

$tag = $entries[$i]["cn"][0]; 
$so = $entries[$i]["operatingsystem"][0]; 
$lastl = $entries[$i]["lastlogon"][0];

     
        mysql_query("
        INSERT INTO 
            $table (tag, so, lastlogh)
        VALUES 
            ('$tag', '$so', '$lastl')
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE         
        tag='$tag',
        so='$so',
        lastlogon='$lastl'
        ");

} 
mysql_close($con); 
ldap_unbind($ad);
if ($entries["count"] > 0)
header("Location: notebooks_list.php")
?>
```

In this query the last logon timestamp is coded like 130276262860634000

So I can export everything to excel and decode it, but I found a code that does that, so it saves time.
I created a new field in the database (lastlogon) and I need to fetch the data from lastlogh field, decode with the new script and store it in the lastlogon field.

This is the script that I found:

```
<?php
function adConvert ($ad) {
  $seconds_ad = $ad / (10000000);
   //86400 -- seconds in 1 day
   $unix = ((1970-1601) * 365 - 3 + round((1970-1601)/4) ) * 86400;

   $timestamp = $seconds_ad - $unix; 
   $normalDate = date("F d, Y", $timestamp);

      return $normalDate;
}

//example: echo adConvert($ad);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Using Mysql API

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $table");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
  $logon_ts = adConvert($row['lastlogh']);
  mysql_query("UPDATE $table SET lastlogon = '$logon_ts' WHERE tag='$row[tag]'");
}
```

I hope this solves your problem.

**Note:** Mysql API is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0. So, It's highly recommended to use Mysqli API for newer developments.

Comment: Ok but first o have to get the value from the lastlogonhidden mysql field.

Comment: I couldn't properly understand your question. Check, whether the updated answer solves your problem...

Comment: OK, i am Portuguese, and will try to explain. Just updated the question.

Comment: check the edited answer... it includes the mysql API which you've used in your code.

Comment: Krishna you are the men: Its late night or i am very stupid, where in my code should i paste this code.

Comment: ok...assuming you have a table in the above mentioned condition, you can execute this query at any point after you connect to database. It will populate the LastLogon field of every row with the converted value. If you can't decide, put it just after your query and run the script. Now, a suggestion: execute my query only once. and, then before filling any thing in the table, delete the lastlogh column and insert the converted timestamp, directly in the LastLogon column.

Comment: For that, Bring a little change in your code `$lastl = adConvert($entries[$i]["lastlogon"][0]);`, and insert `$lastl` into _LastLogon_ column directly instead of _lastlogh_. And remember to remove my script from your code, after using it once. Beacause, my query will run a loop through all your rows each time. If you want to store both values, i.e. the timestamp and the datestring, then also you can do that easily, once you have filled up all the _LastLogon_ cloumn through my script. Just add the LastLogon column in your insert query and provide it with the converted datestring as it's value.

Answer (score 0):

man.. use the distinct for resolve u problem http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp